# Ensure arguments to generic method have same type in trait method

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I have a sealed trait and some case classes that extend that trait, like so:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar extends Foo
case class Baz extends Foo
```

In a different part of my code, I have a trait with a method on it that operates on `Foo`s

```
trait Example {
    def method(arg1: Foo, arg2: Foo)
}
```

However, I would really like to ensure that `arg1` and `arg2` always have the same type; that is, they should both be either `Bar` or `Baz`, and never a mix. My first intuition is to use generics:

```
trait Example {
    def method[T: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: T)
}
```

But I run into two problems:

1. `T` needs to be present on `Example` as far as I can tell. Can I make `method` generic without "infecting" the rest of the trait?
2. I'm not actually sure my type restriction gets the result I would like. Can anyone confirm if my intuition is correct?

Comment: Don't use `T : Foo`, use `T <: Foo`. The former is a context bound, I believe, and Foo does not have type parameters

Comment: `Bar`, `Baz` should be `Bar()`, `Baz()` because they are case classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if you want

> to ensure that `arg1` and `arg2` always have the same type; that is, they should both be either `Bar` or `Baz`, and never a mix

then

```
trait Example {
    def method[T <: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: T) = ???
}
```

is incorrect. `new Example {}.method(Bar(), Baz())` compiles because `T` is inferred to be `Foo`.

Correct is

```
trait Example {
  def method[T <: Foo, U <: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: U)(implicit ev: T =:= U) = ???
}
```

Then `new Example {}.method(Bar(), Baz())` doesn't compile but `new Example {}.method(Bar(), Bar())` and `new Example {}.method(Baz(), Baz())` compile.

More details when generalized type constraints ([`<:<`, `=:=`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/typeConstraints.scala) and even [`<:!<`, `=:!=`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L40-L52)) should be preferred over type bounds (`<:`, `>:`) can be found here:

https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html (See example

```
def tupleIfSubtype[T <: U, U](t: T, u: U) = (t, u)
```

vs.

```
def tupleIfSubtype[T, U](t: T, u: U)(implicit ev: T <:< U) = (t, u)
```

there.)

https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-generics-generalized-type-constraints/ (https://dzone.com/articles/scala-generics-generalized-type-constraints-part-3)

https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2014/09/30/scala-operator/

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `<:`

`:` stands for [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) and works in combination with a type class like `trait Zoo[T]`

`<:` stands for [upper type bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html)

```
trait Example {
    def method[T <: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: T)
}
```

Update:

As @Dmytro Mitin correctly pointed out, the correct solution requires evidence check `=:=` to be performed.

```
def method[T <: Foo, U <: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: U)(implicit ev: T =:= U)
```

Comment: Ah, so I misunderstood what `:` means for type parameters. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Sorry but `def method[T <: Foo](arg1: T, arg2: T)` is incorrect. See details in my answer.